# Software to count structures in an image (rastergraphic)

Tags: image-processing, data-analysis, pixel-graphics

I work with scanned plates from a report of an excavation. I need to count stones build in gravesites. I can do this manually, but it would be very time consuming and frustrating.

I am looking for a software able to count the stones for me. It should be possible since all the stones are simple black ring structures with a plain white background.

I use Windows 7 and OpenSuse 13.1 - both would be ok. I was looking for a free tool, but if there is a recomendable tool for less then 20$ it would be ok too. A web application would be ok too, if it doesn't require to upload the images on a public website.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! You came to the right place. Did I get it right: You are looking for software that counts items on an image? Like "how many black rings are on this image"? What Operating System do you need the software for? Gratis or paid (how much)? Would a web application be okay?

Comment: @akra-kachi Can you add that into the question by [edit]ing please! Adding it in your question means more people see the (important) detail and will stop the question from being closed as unclear!

Comment: @akra-kachi Thank you for your clarification. While I don't know such a tool myself, now the question can be easier found and answered by people who do. One thing though: Here on Software Recommendations (and on the rest of the Stack Exchange family) we prefer not to have "Hi", "Thank you", our names or other formalities in our questions. Keeping it short and to the point is the style of choice here.

Comment: can you attach a  sample image?  Maybe this could be achievable by short scripts using image-processing libraries like open-cv or leptonica - but I'd have to make some tests to be sure.